# PHP not taking the value from HTML

Tags: php, html

So the problem is in my form the only working objects are 
First name, last name, e-mail address, telephone number, comments and room.

But the Number of visitor, arrival date and departure date not working.

I have checked all the id and they are correct.

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="email ">Email Address *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text " name="email " maxlength="80 " size="30 ">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="telephone ">Telephone Number</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text " name="telephone " maxlength="30 " size="30 ">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="comments ">Comments *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <textarea name="comments " maxlength="1000 " cols="25 " rows="6 "></textarea>

      </td>

    </tr>


    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="room">Room</label>

        <td valign="top">
          <select name="room">
            <option value="Ηλεκτρολογοι">Type room 1</option>
            <option value="Γεωπονοι">Tyre room 2</option>

          </select>


        </td>

        <td valign="top">




        </td>

    </tr>



    <tr>

      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center ">





        <input type="image " src="buttononclick.png" alt="Submit Form " />

      </td>

    </tr>

 <tr>
<td valign="top">

 <label for="visitor">Number of Visitor</label>

   <td valign="top">
  <select name="visitor">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">

 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="arrival">Arrival Date</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

<textarea  name="arrival" maxlength="1000" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>

</td>

</tr>




<tr>

<td valign="top">

<label for="departure">Departure Date</label>

</td>

<td valign="top">

<textarea  name="departure" maxlength="1000" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>

</td>

</tr>





 <tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">





 <input type="image" src="buttononclick.png" alt="Submit Form" />

 </td>

 </tr>


  </table>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "antonis997@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])  ||

        !isset($_POST['room']))  { 

        !isset($_POST['visitor'])

        !isset($_POST['arrival'])  ||

        !isset($_POST['departure']))  || { 

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $room = $_POST['room']; // not required

    $visitor = $_POST['visitor']; // not required

    $arrival = $_POST['arrival']; // not required

    $departure = $_POST['departure']; // not required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Room: ".clean_string($room)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Visitor: ".clean_string($visitor)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Arrival: ".clean_string($arrival)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Departure: ".clean_string($departure)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Please edit your code with a: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you also may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using some rich text editor like TinyMCE  for your textareas?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong. What is the expected behaviour and what is the actual behaviour.

Comment: Sorry i am a new user here! When i click on the button , nothing happenig please check the problem online http://antonisem.eu/contact-en.html

Comment: Please read the stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  if you are new.

Comment: that works perfect , i have to say A big thank you and a big sorry for my noob way for the asking

Comment: I have just looked at your live site and noticed that there is no validation on the form page, look at adding either some validation or just the `required` property to your input/textarea tags

Comment: yes that the next part ! but thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in your php code line 47

```
    !isset($_POST['room']))  { 

    !isset($_POST['visitor'])

    !isset($_POST['arrival'])  ||

    !isset($_POST['departure']))  || {
```

Shouldn't it be :

```
    !isset($_POST['room'])  || 

    !isset($_POST['visitor']) ||

    !isset($_POST['arrival'])  || 

    !isset($_POST['departure']))  {
```

Comment: that works perfect , i have to say A big thank you and a big sorry for my noob way for the asking

Comment: We all started from the bottom to reach the top, keep going bro

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is a problem in the isset sections

```
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])  ||

    !isset($_POST['room']))  { 

    !isset($_POST['visitor'])

    !isset($_POST['arrival'])  ||

    !isset($_POST['departure']))  || { 

die('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}
```